# grails postgres Message: ERROR: column this_.id does not exist

Tags: postgresql, grails

grails with postgres for User domain.

```
 Message: ERROR: column this_.id does not exist
```

Answer (score 7):

Got the issue.
For User domain, I've postgres table as "user". So by default when it is trying to query user table, its not querying with "user.id". There is something wrong with postgres for "user" table.

So I updated my "user" table to "myapp_user" table. The problem got solved.

Answer (score 5):

The word 'user' may be reserved by dbms.

```
static mapping = {
    table '`User`'
    password column: '`password`'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because table name `user` already occupied by defalut by Postgres. Try query w/ schema (`public` by default) like in `phpPgAdmin`:

```
SELECT * FROM "public"."user"
```