# Grails 3.3.0 with PostgreSQL 10.1 gives column this_.id does not exist error

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I have to make a Grails 3.3.0 web interface for my internship with PostgreSQL version 10.1 as database and spring-security-core version 3.2.0.
I used version 42.1.4 as a JDBC driver for PostgreSQL.

I've installed PostgreSQL on my Linux laptop and created the webInterfaceDev database with the user postgres.

However, every time I want to start the project I get an error that the column this_.id does not exist. 
This is the error that I get:

```
2017-11-16 14:42:21.464 ERROR --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column this_.id does not exist
    Position: 8
2017-11-16 14:42:21.504 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column this_.id does not exist
    Position: 8
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:99)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertJdbcAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:731)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertHibernateAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:719)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:303)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:243)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:117)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.findWhere(AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:611)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.findWhere(GormStaticApi.groovy:770)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.internalFindOrCreate(GormStaticApi.groovy:1172)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.findOrSaveWhere(GormStaticApi.groovy:813)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.findOrSaveWhere(GormEntity.groovy:886)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1446)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:899)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
        at com.domain.auth.User.findOrSaveWhere(User.groovy)
        at com.domain.auth.User$findOrSaveWhere.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at web_interface.BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:8)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:535)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:528)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:504)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:74)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
        at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:261)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:387)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at web_interface.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column this_.id does not exist
    Position: 8
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2122)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1905)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1787)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:385)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi$_findWhere_closure17.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:124)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.doInHibernate(Unknown Source)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:299)
        ... 63 common frames omitted

2017-11-16 14:42:21.518 ERROR --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000478: Unsuccessful: alter table user_role drop constraint FK859n2jvi8ivhui0rl0esws6o
2017-11-16 14:42:21.528 ERROR --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000478: Unsuccessful: drop table user cascade

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Below is the code that I used:

grails-app/conf/application.yml

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password:

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:postgresql:webInterfaceDev
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

I have added the following line in build.gradle: 
`compile ‘org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4.jre7`.

Below is the build.gradle code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.2"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "web_interface"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencies {
    //plugins needed to make the user system
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.1.1'
    //end of the plugins needed
    //postgresql
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4.jre7'
    //end
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Comment: Is `com.domain.auth.User` your own User implementation? Are you calling `User.findOrSaveWhere(...` somewhere? bootstrap maybe? can we see this & the domain class

Comment: @MikeW I have installed the spring security core and more I have not done yet. I have Role, User and UserRole as domain, which are generated by spring security core. This is the first time for me that I work with grails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in PostgreSQL, `user` is reserved word. You have to put double quote `"` when create **user** table with SQL-

```
create table "user" (...);
```

In your User domain put in :

```
static mapping = {
    table '`User`'
    password column: '`password`'
}
```

Related post :

[grails postgres Message: ERROR: column this_.id does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407782/grails-postgres-message-error-column-this-id-does-not-exist)

[Cannot create a database table named 'user' in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256124/cannot-create-a-database-table-named-user-in-postgresql)

Comment: I have already changed that in the User domain (I found the same posts).
I still get the above error message.

Comment: I think I have it now.
I have applied the same code as you said but with a small difference, namely, after table there is a colon.
I have removed the colon and now it seems to be working.

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved. I hope my answer was useful a bit.  Thanks anyway. For more reference to `table` please check https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/table.html